# Please explain the output in this setTimeOut() function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, logic, settimeout

I tried running this snippet of code for which I tried consoling the `i`  value inside `setTimeOut()` function and the **o/p** `i` got is **5** for **5 times** with a time interval of `3 seconds` each, can anyone please explain this snippet?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(function() {
      /////Why is this console.log printing 5?
      console.log(i);
    },

    i * 3000);
  console.log("i:", i)
}
```

OutPut:

```
0
i: 0
1
i: 1
2
i: 2
3
i: 3
4
i: 4
5
5
5
5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this code

```
console.log("a"),
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("b");
},3000);
console.log("C")
```

The output of the code will be **a, C, b**
Due to setTimeout is a call back function. And callback function executes after executing every line of code present in a function. Make your code accordingly with this theory it might help you to clear your concepts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The callback passed to `setTimeout` is added to the event queue after the interval. As the interval increases in each iteration by 3 seconds(`i * 3000`) the 5s are logged with an interval of 3 seconds.

[More about event queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

All of the logs inside the callback are 5 because of the function scoped variable declaration `var i=0`. When the loop completes and callbacks in the queue are executed, the variable `i` will have the value 5 (as the condition `i<5` fails when `i` is 5).

[Scope of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of variable "i" increased by one after the loop close.
Your loop run with `i=4` then after reaching the end of the for loop block it gets increase by 1 and became 5, after increasing the condition get checked `5<5` and the loop exit.
The javascript compiler store variables declared with `var` keyword on it's global storage so the end of the loop won't free the memory it reserve. You can change this behavior by declare variable I with `let` keyword instead.